# I'm trying to create an error message if the data entered in an array is less than zero, input validation

Tags: java, arrays, validation, loops, methods

This method allows the user to input the rainfall for every month of the year.  I'm trying to prevent data less than zero from being stored in the array.  I'm using a do-while loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to check if the input is less than zero.  Thanks for your help guys, cheers!

```
public static double[] getRainFall()
    {
        double[] rainfallMonths = new double[12];
        double[] rainfall = new double[12];

        do
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < rainfallMonths.length; x++)
            {
                    System.out.print("What is the rainfall for month #" + (x + 1) + ": ");
                rainfallMonths[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
                rainfall[x] = rainfallMonths[x];

                if(rainfallMonths < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
                }
            }
        }while(rainfallMonths < 0);


        for(int count = 0; count < rainfallMonths.length; count++)
        {
            System.out.println("Rainfall Month #" + (count + 1) + ": " + rainfall[count]);
        }

        return rainfall;
    }
```

Comment: `if(rainfallMonths[x] < 0)`...but you will want to change you loop around this point...

Comment: `rainfallMonths` is just a reference. You might want to check for `rainFallMonths[index]`

Comment: Do u want to end the loop while rainfallMonths < 0 , and u have already mistake your code.See above comment of @MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is a little off, not to mention that you're trying to compare an array to an `int`...

First, the logic...

```
do 
    for x = 0 to rainfallMonths.length -1 do
        ... get input...
while value < 0
```

The problem here is, you've already assigned the input to all the elements of the array in the `for-next` loop, but then you are trying to validate the value that was input outside of the `for-next` which is likely never to return a valid result...and it's too late...

Instead, you want to reverse the logic...

```
for x = 0 to rainfallMonths.length -1 do
    do 
        value = get input from user
    while value < 0
    rainfallMonths[x] = value
```

Next, `rainfallMonths` is a reference to an array, this isn't actually what you want to be checking against, you need to be checking against one it's values or elements, for example...

```
while (rainfallMonths[x] < 0);
```

And if none of that made sense...

```
public static double[] getRainFall()
{
    double[] rainfallMonths = new double[12];
    double[] rainfall = new double[12];

    for(int x = 0; x < rainfallMonths.length; x++)
    {
        double input = 0;
        System.out.print("What is the rainfall for month #" + (x + 1) + ": ");
        do {
            rainfallMonths[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            rainfall[x] = rainfallMonths[x];
            if(input < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
            }
        } while (rainfallMonths[x] < 0);    
    }


    for(int count = 0; count < rainfallMonths.length; count++)
    {
        System.out.println("Rainfall Month #" + (count + 1) + ": " + rainfall[count]);
    }

    return rainfall;
}
```

You might want to take a refresher on [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) which should help ;)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I should have had the do-while inside of the for-loop.  I'm taking a java course at city college and arrays are starting to get a little tricky.  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
double temp = -1;
for(int x = 0; x < rainfallMonths.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.print("What is the rainfall for month #" + (x + 1) + ": ");
            temp = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if(temp < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Input is Invalid");
                x--; //if you want the user to maybe try to repeat this month again?
            }
            else
            {
                rainfallMonths[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
                rainfall[x] = rainfallMonths[x];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've never seen it done like this.  thanks for the help!